# is it possible to have multiple azure function handlers as endpoint for an event subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template, azure-eventgrid

[image]

How to add another function in the endpoint section. I tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-quickstart-powershell#subscribe-to-a-topic)

```
New-AzEventGridSubscription `
  -EventSubscriptionName demoViewerSub `
  -Endpoint $endpoint `
  -ResourceGroupName gridResourceGroup `
  -TopicName $topicname
```

it just replaces the existing endpoint.is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to give it a different name, `EventSubscriptionName`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but event subscription keeps increasing if a new handler needs to be added

Comment: @saicharan, based on the AEG design, the Event Subscription represents an entity for **reliable delivery** an event message to one destination handler using a retry policy included a deadlettering. However, your scenario can be completed using one azure function as a message publisher with a output binding to the SignalR Service broadcaster in the loosely decoupled manner.